iOS 17 MapKit .standard doesn't allow for a globe view when zoomed out
I'm working on setting up a very basic mapview with MapKit for my iPhone on iOS 17. I noticed that the Apple maps app doesn't have this issue but I really couldn't find much about this topic other than a thread in August of 2023 where a poster said that there was a bug not allowing the .standard map style to appear as a globe when zoomed out.
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        
        // Set map type to hybrid flyover for a more globe-like appearance
        mapView.mapType = .hybridFlyover
        
        // Configure camera for a globe-like view
        let camera = MKMapCamera()
        camera.centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
        camera.altitude = 20000000 // Adjust altitude for desired zoom level
        camera.pitch = 60 // Adjust pitch for a more globe-like view
        camera.heading = 0
        
        mapView.setCamera(camera, animated: false)
        
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        // Update the view if needed
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MapViewRepresentable()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

anyway, that is my code and I've really tried all sorts of ways to get the .standard map style to appear as a globe, but to the best of my knowledge it isn't doable in iOS 17 and I can't seem to figure out why? It's quite puzzling as the satellite view works just fine.

Discovered the same issue and went on a mad goose chase looking for an answer. It appears it's either intentional or unconcerning to apple, which makes no sense but cant find many posts about it aside from these two from the apple dev forums with official responses:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/101479
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/760542
The first one is from 2018 confirming it's not available with no explanation.
The second is from this year (2024) with the Apple engineer requesting the poster create a bug report explaining why that would be useful.
As of now it's unclear if they'll ever fix or address this unfortunately.

Hey so that other question was actually me. Apple seems to have w done nothing about it since.
One question for you though. Have you tried using UIKit? I’ve just migrated my project away from Apple Maps since but the only way I see it potentially working is if you use the UIKit Apple map API since it’s so much more fleshed out. Please let me know if you try this as it really is unfortunate.
There truly are hardly any good options it seems. Mapbox API is terrible, Google maps is tedious, at a certain point I was considering making my own maps. Everything feels like a bad choice imo.
